# Matching exactly 4 digits not working

Tags: regex, bash

I have this line in which I want to change the port after the url:

```
url: 'http://mypage5.url.com:2567',
```

And I'm trying to replace it with sed using the following regex:

```
sed -i "s/:[0-9]{4,5}/:$OTHERNUMBER/" $FILENAME
```

and it does nothing. I have tried matching only one digit (:[0-9]) and it works fine. What may I be doing wrong?

Comment: Use `-r` to make it `sed -ri "s/:[0-9]{4,5}/:$OTHERNUMBER/" $FILENAME`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sed uses its own [regex syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html):

> `\{i,j\}`
>     Matches between `i` and `j`, inclusive, sequences.

So you have to escape the curly braces:

```
sed -i "s/:[0-9]\\{4,5\\}/:$OTHERNUMBER/" $FILENAME
```

One escape is for sed, the other is for bash. sed will see `\{4,5\}`.

Answer (score 0):

On my mac:

```
$ cat file.txt 
url: 'http://mypage5.url.com:44445'
url: 'http://mypage5.url.com:44445'

$ export OTHERNUMBER=3434; sed -Ei ""  "s/:[0-9]{4,5}/:$OTHERNUMBER/" file.txt ; cat file.txt 
url: 'http://mypage5.url.com:3434'
url: 'http://mypage5.url.com:3434'
```

I use the extended regular expression option (-E) so that do not have to escape so much.

`-E      Interpret regular expressions as extended (modern) regular expressions rather than basic regular expressions (BRE's).`

On linux, I believe, you could do (do not have a linux box handy but this is how it should be):

```
sed -Ei "s/:[0-9]{4,5}/:$OTHERNUMBER/" file.txt
```